# XPages: Login not working?

Tags: authentication, xpages

im having a huge problem with the login node in the Web Browser. I click "Login" on the top right corner of my layout. It gets me to the login screen. All fine so far. Then im trying to login and as soon as i typed in my login-data and press "Sign in" Its just reloading the login-page. It doesnt take me back to the site i came from, it doesnt log me in, nothing. Im only having this issue in the web browser since it automatically logs you in, in the Notes Client. Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for the bad english.

Sincerly,
Brugen

Comment: Are you using internet sites and Multiple Servers (SSO) authentication? Then make sure that the URL in the LTPA configuration matches the URL used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Paul...

You could try: `http://yourserver.com/names.nsf?open&login` to check if your login is correct - disregarding any issues with your XPage.

Next, have a look at your server console to see if anything is written there to indicate a problem. If so it is easiest to use something like the [XPages Log Reader](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8UXP49) to investigate the log files on the server. From the link there is a link to the project where you can download the database.

HTH :-)

/John

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is assuming too little knowledge, but are you trying the correct username and password? By default Notes Client and web passwords are not synchronised, it's a separate HTTPPassword field in your Person document on the server. After changing, it may take a few minutes to take effect.